# Add polygon name to a data frame using sf and tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, gis, r-sf

This question ought to be asked and answered here previously. I cannot find the solution, so will ask. Please point to the duplicate question if there is one.

I am trying to append a data frame (or a tibble to be precise) of geographic data points with information of which polygon each row of data lies in. I know how to do this in `sp` and am trying to find the optimal `sf`/`tidyverse` way. The solution I have come up with based on `sp` to `sf` dictionary [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/wiki/Migrating) appears unnecessarily complicated.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(tidyverse)

polys <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package ="sf")) %>% 
  sf::st_transform(4326)
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source 
#>   `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/sf/shape/nc.shp' 
#>   using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27

set.seed(1)
points <- tibble::tibble(
  lon = sample(seq(st_bbox(polys)[c("xmin")], st_bbox(polys)[c("xmax")], 0.01), 
               size = 1e3,
               replace = TRUE
  ),
  lat = sample(seq(st_bbox(polys)[c("ymin")], st_bbox(polys)[c("ymax")], 0.01), 
               size = 1e3,
               replace = TRUE
  ),
  somedata = sample(letters, size = 1e3, replace = TRUE)
)

# Here is a way to do what I want. The code seems unnecessarily complicated, however.

points %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  mutate(county = 
           polys[
             sapply(st_intersects(.,polys), 
                        function(z) if (length(z)==0) NA_integer_ else z[1]),
             ]$NAME
  ) 
#> Simple feature collection with 1000 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32377 ymin: 33.88212 xmax: -75.47377 ymax: 36.58212
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 3
#>    somedata             geometry county     
#>  * <chr>             <POINT [°]> <chr>      
#>  1 m        (-75.97377 34.19212) <NA>       
#>  2 z        (-77.54377 36.38212) Northampton
#>  3 m        (-83.04377 33.94212) <NA>       
#>  4 h        (-79.24377 36.04212) Orange     
#>  5 x        (-79.62377 36.21212) Guilford   
#>  6 m        (-81.34377 36.37212) Ashe       
#>  7 w        (-81.63377 34.00212) <NA>       
#>  8 g        (-82.46377 34.35212) <NA>       
#>  9 f        (-81.26377 34.38212) <NA>       
#> 10 x        (-78.36377 35.02212) Sampson    
#> # … with 990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

A simpler way to do this, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combine here `st_join` selecting just the desired variables of the polygon and renaming on tidyverse style. I think this is a bit more simpler than your proposed approach

**Data**

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(tidyverse)

polys <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) %>%
  sf::st_transform(4326)
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27


set.seed(1)
points <- tibble::tibble(
  lon = sample(seq(st_bbox(polys)[c("xmin")], st_bbox(polys)[c("xmax")], 0.01),
    size = 1e3,
    replace = TRUE
  ),
  lat = sample(seq(st_bbox(polys)[c("ymin")], st_bbox(polys)[c("ymax")], 0.01),
    size = 1e3,
    replace = TRUE
  ),
  somedata = sample(letters, size = 1e3, replace = TRUE)
)
```

**My approach**

```r
points %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  # Spatial join selecting just NAME variable
  st_join(polys[, "NAME"]) %>%
  # Rename tidyverse style
  rename(county = NAME)
#> Simple feature collection with 1000 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32377 ymin: 33.88212 xmax: -75.47377 ymax: 36.58212
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 3
#>    somedata             geometry county     
#>    <chr>             <POINT [°]> <chr>      
#>  1 m        (-75.97377 34.19212) <NA>       
#>  2 z        (-77.54377 36.38212) Northampton
#>  3 m        (-83.04377 33.94212) <NA>       
#>  4 h        (-79.24377 36.04212) Orange     
#>  5 x        (-79.62377 36.21212) Guilford   
#>  6 m        (-81.34377 36.37212) Ashe       
#>  7 w        (-81.63377 34.00212) <NA>       
#>  8 g        (-82.46377 34.35212) <NA>       
#>  9 f        (-81.26377 34.38212) <NA>       
#> 10 x        (-78.36377 35.02212) Sampson    
#> # ... with 990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Didn't know that you can use `st_join` like that. Thanks for teaching me something new :)

Comment: I noticed that these two approaches (the one by the OP and here) do not produce identical results. Might have something to do with how points laying exactly on the vertices or edges get assigned to the polygons. Just mentioning it here in case it is relevant for someone.